# Minitest/Mocha: Testing that a value changes multiple times

Tags: ruby, minitest, ruby-mocha

Let's say I have a service class as such:

```
class FooService

  def self.execute(foo_id)
    Foo.find(foo_id).tap do |foo|
      foo.update_attribute :status, :working
      do_work(foo)
      foo.update_attribute :status, :done
    end
  end

end
```

A simple test for this method in Minitest with Mocha:

```
test 'executing the service' do
  @foo = Foo.first

  FooService.expects(:do_work).with(@foo)

  FooService.execute(@foo.id)

  assert_equal :done, @foo.reload.status
end
```

What would be the best way to test that the `status` attribute was set to `:working`?

I've tried using `Foo.any_instance.expects(:update_attribute).with(:status, :working)` but since there is no way to call the original implementation in Mocha this has bad side effects.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to get `do_work` to raise an error. That should stop the process before the end of the routine and leave `foo` in status `working`

```
FooService.expects(:do_work).raises(Exception, 'foo')
assert_equal :working, @foo.reload.status
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let's say I already have exception handling that changes the status to `:failed` and a test case similar to the above that asserts that. In theory I could use two different error classes but it just feels "wrong".